# "Index Match" functionality in Excel not captured in pandas Merge (or is it?)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, merge, vlookup

There are several posts on replicating Excel's Index-Match functionality in pandas using merge, but merge doesn't seem to cover one of the most basic features of Excel's Index-Match.

I have a passable workaround but I'm sure there's a better way.  And of course I may be missing something obvious about pandas.merge.

Let's say we have the following two tables

```
t1
    numbers letters
0   1623    a
1   3266    b
2   3672    c

t2
    letters target
0   a   ddd
1   a   ddd
2   a   ddd
3   b   eee
4   b   eee
5   b   eee
6   c   fff
7   c   fff
8   c   fff
```

and that we want to add a column to t1 that simply maps values from t2.target based on the values in t2.letters to yield this:

```
    numbers letters target
0   1623    a   ddd
1   3266    b   eee
2   3672    c   fff
```

With pandas.merge, it seems that all of the repeated values in t2.target have to show up in the resultant DataFrame, like so:

```
    numbers letters target
0   1623    a   ddd
1   1623    a   ddd
2   1623    a   ddd
3   3266    b   eee
4   3266    b   eee
5   3266    b   eee
6   3672    c   fff
7   3672    c   fff
8   3672    c   fff
```

In many cases however this isn't want we want.

One workaround is to use .duplicated():

```
t2_unique = t2[t2.target.duplicated==False]
t1.merge(t2_unique)
```

This yields the desired 3x3 table above.  But given how thoughtful and comprehensive the rest of pandas is, and how often people do this sort of thing in Excel, I find it hard to believe that there isn't a more direct route to this kind of output in pandas, either as part of merge or something else.

Thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, one person's liability is another person's feature. It would be bad if merge threw away records. Clean your data before doing your substantive operations. You are doing a join operation, and since there are duplicates at least in the thee variables shown (there may be more variables that are different), the join respects that. In addition, you are really doing a mapping of values from letters to target. But for this to be meaningful you again need unique key:value pairs to avoid ambiguity.

The mapping can be done easily, though.

```
t2.set_index('letters',inplace=True)
t2_map = t2.target.to_dict()
```

This actually yields a well-behaved dictionary:

```
{'a': 'ddd', 'b': 'eee', 'c': 'fff'}
```

You can then use this to map the `target` to `letters` in `t1`.

```
t1['target']=t1.letters.map(t2_map)
t1

      numbers letters target
0     1623       a    ddd
1     3266       b    eee
2     3672       c    fff
```

Comment: Thanks!  I knew there had to be a more explicit route.